# Notify when file read

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, c, events

How can I register to event that let me know when specific file is read in linux?

Can implement in c or in bash /shell script

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/linux-file-access-monitoring

Comment: @roaima The purported dupe asks a different thing -- the title is misleading; please read the actual text of the question. This question was probably already asked a lot of times, but not there.

Comment: @mosvy the answers on the suggested dup are applicable here too. They say the same as your answer.

Comment: No, they're not applicable. They don't show how to monitor whenever a read(2) is done, as in my example. And they're cluttered with a lot of confusing stuff: loggedfs, .bash_history, etc. As I said, there probably is a dupe for this, but not *that*.

Comment: How about https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207304/how-to-monitor-the-opening-and-closing-of-files for a less-confusing duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Use `inotify(7)`, `inotify_add_watch(2)` with `IN_ACCESS`, `inotifywait(1)`, etc.

Example: In a window:

```
while read f; do echo "$f"; sleep 3; done </path/to/your/file
...
```

In another window:

```
inotifywait -me access /path/to/your/file
/path/to/your/file ACCESS
/path/to/your/file ACCESS
/path/to/your/file ACCESS
...
```

Comment: Looking in linux not Windows